# find index of object from list of objects

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I've got a list

```
List<SalesmanDetails> salesmanList
```

Salesman details has name, phone number, region.
I've got two windows forms, one that has a list box, the other that allows the user to edit information by changing the values in textboxes.

The list box is either populated by the "view All" button which displays all the salesmen in the list or the user can search a name (e.g Bob Smith) and all the Bob Smith's in the list will be displayed in the listbox.

this is the code i've got for view all:

```
try
            {                    

                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (SalesmanDetails details in salesmanList)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", details.firstName, details.surname));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

this is the code for search name:

```
private void btnSearchName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (SalesmanDetails search in salesmanList)
        {
            if (search.firstName.ToLower().Contains(searchName.ToLower()) | search.surname.ToLower().Contains(searchName.ToLower()))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", search.firstName, search.surname));                        
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

when the user double clicks a person on the listbox, the second form for editing is shown with the details of that person. So if Bob Smith is clicked, the second form will be populated with Bob Smith as the name, his phone number and his region.

how do I go  about populating the edit form when a person is searched for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind to the List.

Add a property to your object named FullName:

```
public string FullName { get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", search.firstName, search.surname); } }
```

Then bind:

```
listBox1.DataSource = currentSalesmanList;  // filtered or all
listBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName"
listBox1.ValueMember = "SalesmanId";  // (optional) something to uniquely identify
```

Then handle the SelectedValueChanged event - the SelectedIndex will be the same index in your cached list of Salesmen:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        Salesman salesman = currentSalesmanList[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        textBox1.Text = salesman.firstName;
    }
}
```

Rewrite your search to filter the main salesmanList dumping the results into the "currentSalesmanList", then bind to it.

```
private void btnSearchName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentSalesmanList = salesmanList.Where((s) => s.firstName.ToLower().Contains(searchName.ToLower()));

    listBox1.DataSource = currentSalesmanList;  // filtered or all
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName"
    listBox1.ValueMember = "SalesmanId";  // (optional) something to uniquely identify

}
```

Comment: +1 for the `ValueMember`. I was just figuring out this property now.

Comment: for the selectedValueChanged, the textbox is in another form, so how would I populate it?

Comment: You need another global / static (or otherwise, cached object) named "CurrentSalesman".  It will represent the currently selected salesman.  Populate this cached object with the object selected from the list in "listBox1_SelectedValueChanged".

Comment: what about the currentSalesmanList? is that a private variable that i populate when the form loads?

Comment: Your application should maintain some form of "State" - Current[SomeObject] simply represents the current state of something.  Check out [.NET's MemoryCache](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net-4-0).  There are many other ways, i.e. static collections, static objects, ThreadLocal, etc... so it really depends on your application's needs taking into consideration things like performance, concurrency, scalability, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Do a trick :

define a global array , this array is going to save the index of people who have been filtered by search .

in this example :

```
public List<Int32> myList = new List<Int32>();
```

then define a counter in your search function . and change it like this :

```
private void btnSearchName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 counter = 0;
        try
        {
            foreach (SalesmanDetails search in salesmanList)
            {
                if (search.firstName.ToLower().Contains(searchName.ToLower()) | search.surname.ToLower().Contains(searchName.ToLower()))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", search.firstName, search.surname));
                    myList.Add(counter);
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

you are going to have the real index of filtered people in myList .

using this list you can catch the selected index's data through sealsmanList.